# Copy all dependencies jars from child projects into parent project directory

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to build a Maven parent project script which incorporates a 3rd party project (with all its dependencies) and another couple of projects of mine.

I'd like to copy all dependencies (I mean **ALL** dependencies, including jars requested by other dependencies which in turn are requested by one of my child project) to a parent project directory, e.g. "lib", so that I can just run java with a wildcard classpath:

```
java -cp "lib/*" package.blah.blah.Main
```

I tried with various methods using the `maven-dependency-plugin` such as `copy-dependencies`, but all I can point Maven to is my own child projects, not their dependencies (I mean in the parent project pom).

This is the parent project pom I've been writing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <properties>
    <server.version>7.0.2</server.version>
    <ext.version>1.0-alpha3-SNAPSHOT</ext.version>
  </properties>

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.kontalk</groupId>
  <artifactId>tigase-kontalk</artifactId>
  <version>devel</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <modules>
      <module>../tigase-server/modules/master</module>
      <module>../tigase-extension</module>
  </modules>

  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>             
              <id>copy-artifact</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>copy</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                      <groupId>org.kontalk</groupId>
                      <artifactId>tigase-server</artifactId>
                      <version>${server.version}</version>
                      <type>jar</type>
                    </artifactItem>
                    <artifactItem>
                      <groupId>org.kontalk</groupId>
                      <artifactId>tigase-extension</artifactId>
                      <version>${ext.version}</version>
                      <type>jar</type>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
                <outputDirectory>bin</outputDirectory>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kontalk</groupId>
            <artifactId>tigase-server</artifactId>
            <version>${server.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kontalk</groupId>
            <artifactId>tigase-extension</artifactId>
            <version>${ext.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

It will copy just the two direct child project jars in the bin directory, but nothing else.
I'm thinking of doing a manual copy (as in a Maven copy) to brutally copy all jars from my child projects' `target/dependency` directories, but it just seems... brutal.

If it can't be done with the existing Maven software, I can even be content with using maven exec directly (which, I hope, should set up classpath automatically, right?)

EDIT: I'd like to modify the child projects poms as little as possible, especially the 3rd party one.

Comment: "java -cp lib/*.jar"
I'm afraid that won't work. This expression will be resolved to "java -cp lib/lib1.jar lib/lib2.jar ..." instead of "java -cp lib/lib1.jar:lib/lib2.jar:..."

Comment: Sorry I've fixed it to not shell escape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `copy-dependencies`. This is the main project pom:

```
<build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>install</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/jars</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>jars</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>../tigase-extension/target/lib</directory>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>junit*</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </resource>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>../tigase-server/target/lib</directory>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>junit*</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </resource>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>../tigase-extension/target</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>tigase-extension-*.jar</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

In the submodules I've added to the same plugin this code:

```
      <execution>
        <phase>install</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
```

Basically, the submodules copy their dependency jars into target/lib, then the main project copies those jars into its own jars folder.

It has some project-specific filenames and other hard-coded things, but still I think this is the best option if I want to use only Maven-provided tools. Probably a new Maven plugin would have been optimal, but I don't really have the time.

Comment: This didn't work for me. if i check dependencies count in parent folder, it's less than dependencies count in child modules

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build a simply runnable jar file with maven then you can use this config:

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dist</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                            <finalName>yourJarName</finalName>
                            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>your.MainClass</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>dist</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>single</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

then you can build it using `mvn clean package -Pdist`

edit: then you can run it with `java -jar target/yourJarName.jar`

Comment: Thanks! This has the side effect of producing a whole bunch of stuff such as child project's documentation packages etc. Can I exclude them or move this "step" to the install goal?

Comment: Besides, it doesn't work (empty jar, only a manifest file). It took a long time, sorry if I tell you just now. I guess it doesn't consider child projects dependencies?

Comment: I use it here and it works: https://github.com/erosb/logika
I hope you can figure out whats the difference between logika and your project

Comment: In your script there is a much simpler situation though: your main project is also the ones with the direct dependencies. I need to assembly dependencies from all the submodules/child projects.

Comment: I have an other more complex module too but not on this comp. I'll look after it tomorrow

Comment: Ok thanks. In the meantime, I'm brutally copying the jar files from the submodule through copy-resources (I know, terrible...)

Comment: here is an other snippet for your pom.xml:

<build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
     <archive>
      <manifest>
       <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
       <mainClass>your.MainClass</mainClass>
      </manifest>
     </archive>
     <descriptorRefs>
      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
     </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
 </build>

Comment: I'm sorry but that simply does not fit. I ended up using copy-dependencies altogether. Thanks anyway.